# Jquery - How to add text into text box in div above?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add text into a hidden text box in the div below when a use clicks delete...

Html

```
<div class="documentRow">    
<div class="documentHeader">
    <b>Title:</b> 
     <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Required" id="EventDocuments_1__Title" name="EventDocuments[1].Title" style="width:100px" type="text" value="test.doc">   
</div>
<div class="documentDelete">
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Delete field is required." id="EventDocuments_1__Delete" name="EventDocuments[1].Delete" type="hidden" value="False">
</div>
<div class="deleteDoc">
     <button class="button delDocButton ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Delete</span></button>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".delDocButton").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().toggle();
        $(this).parent().find(".documentDelete input").val("True");  
        return false;
    });
```

i have several of these "rows" on the page, so i cant reference the text box by id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is this line:

```
$(this).parent().find(".documentDelete input").val("True");
```

`$(this).parent()` is the direct parent of the button (`<div class="deleteDoc">`), and your hidden field is not in there so it wont `find` it.

To save having to repeat the calls to `parent()` I suggest sometihng likethis:

```
$(".delDocButton").click(function() {
    var $container = $(this).parent().parent();
    $container.toggle();  
    $(".documentDelete input",$container).val("True");  
    return false;
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/SqHzU/

Comment: that toggles the row, but still doesn't set the hidden field value to true

Comment: @Beginner - I'd missed a `$` off of the line that does it... recheck the code.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line

`$(this).parent().find(".documentDelete input").val("True");`

With this

`$(this).parent().siblings(".documentDelete").find("input").val("True");`

Answer (score 0):

Even this should work:

```
 $(this).parent().find(".documentDelete").find('input').val("True");
```

Answer (score 0):

u will also check this

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umairnoor84/hf4sx/)

hopefully its usefull